# Cleaning up java code, multiple if statements

Tags: java, code-cleanup

I'm supposed to clean up a java code, got rid of lots of stuff, but should is there anything else to clean, maybe somehow get rid of multiple if statements, without totally rewriting this code? Can't seem to figure it out as they are so different to stack them in one 'if'. Any ideas?

```
 public class Calc {
           // employee types
           public static final int SELLER;
           public static final int COOK;
           public static final int CHIEF;



       public static void main(final String[] args) {
              Calc c = new Calc();
              System.err.println(c.pay(CHIEF) + " should be 66");
       }

       private int pay(final int type, final int h) {
              int Sum = 0;
              if (type == SELLER) {
                     if (h > 8) { 
                           Sum = 20 * (h - 8);  
                           Sum += 80;
                     } else {
                           Sum += 10 * h;
                     }
              }
              if (type == COOK) {
                     if (h > 8) { 
                           Sum = 30 * (h - 8); 
                           Sum += 15 * 8;
                     } else {
                           Sum += 15 * h;
                     }
              }
              if (type == CHIEF) {
                     if (h > 8) { 
                           Sum = 66 * (h - 8); 
                           Sum += 22 * 8;
                     } else {
                           Sum += 22 * h;
                     }
              }
              if (h > 20) {
                     if (type == SELLER) {
                           Sum += 10;
                     }
                     if (type == COOK) {
                           Sum += 20;
                     }
                     if (type == CHIEF) {
                           Sum += 30;
                     }
              }
              return Sum;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The code you wrote is purely procedural and in most cases is considered a bad practice while writing in Object Oriented language like Java. You should learn about the power of polymorphism and should not perform a type check manually:

```
if (type == COOK) { //Avoid doing this in OO languages!
```

You should think of your domain entities (employees) as objects and each specific type of employee can define its own rules for calculating pay.

Let's create an abstract class Employee with single abstract method `int calculatePay(int h)`:

```
public abstract class Employee {
    abstract int calculatePay(int h);
}
```

Word *abstract* means that this method has no actual implementation but all the logic for calculating pay will be put in the subclasses Seller, Cook and Chief:

```
public class Cook extends Employee {

    public Cook() {}

    int calculatePay(int h) {
        int sum = (h > 20) ? 20 : 0;
        if (h > 8) {
            sum = 30 * (h - 8);
            sum += 15 * 8;
        } else {
            sum += 15 * h;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Note the line:

```
    int sum = (h > 20) ? 20 : 0;
```

This is *ternary operator*. Sometimes it is good for conditional assignment in expressions. Thus we initialize the `sum` variable with 20 when `h` is greater than 20 and with 0 otherwise. Now we don't use extra `if` statement in the end of our method.

Now each employee is responsible for calculating pay for itself and there is no need to perform a type check in PayCalculator class - it is dynamically resolved in runtime which code to execute based on parameter type:

```
public class PayCalculator {

    int pay(Employee e, int hours) {
        return e.calculatePay(hours);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Seller seller = new Seller();
        Cook cook = new Cook();
        Chief chief = new Chief();

        PayCalculator calc = new PayCalculator();

        System.out.println("Seller is payed " + calc.pay(seller, 15));
        System.out.println("Cook is payed " + calc.pay(cook, 10));
        System.out.println("Chief is payed " + calc.pay(chief, 22));
    }
}
```

This is called **polymorhism**. If this term is new to you, you can read Oracle tutorial in OOP basics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

*Thinking in Java* book by Bruce Eckel also has a good explanation of basic OOP concepts.

Comment: This is excellent explanation, for sure! This was actually written by my teacher and probably meant to be as ugly as it is. I had a feeling your approach could be achieved somehow, but I couldn't pull this off. Thanks for making my learning curve easier!

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.Map` save a lot of if/else, and use `Enum` as choices for user

```
public class X {

    public enum Type {
        SELLER, COOK, CHIEF
    }

    private Map<Type, Integer> constantValue1;
    private Map<Type, Integer> constantValue2;
    private Map<Type, Integer> additionalValue;

    public X() {
        initialConstantValue1();
        initialConstantValue2();
        initialAdditionalValue();
    }

    private void initialConstantValue1() {
        constantValue1 = new HashMap<>();
        constantValue1.put(Type.SELLER, 20);
        constantValue1.put(Type.COOK, 30);
        constantValue1.put(Type.CHIEF, 66);
    }

    private void initialConstantValue2() {
        constantValue2 = new HashMap<>();
        constantValue2.put(Type.SELLER, 10);
        constantValue2.put(Type.COOK, 15);
        constantValue2.put(Type.CHIEF, 22);
    }

    private void initialAdditionalValue() {
        additionalValue = new HashMap<>();
        additionalValue.put(Type.SELLER, 10);
        additionalValue.put(Type.COOK, 20);
        additionalValue.put(Type.CHIEF, 30);
    }

    int pay(final Type type, final int h) {
        int sum = 0;
        if (h > 8) {
            sum = constantValue1.get(type) * (h - 8);
            sum += constantValue2.get(type) * 8;
        }
        else {
            sum += constantValue2.get(type) * h;
        }
        if (h > 20) {
            sum += additionalValue.get(type);
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of cleaning up or implementing it with minimal `if` statements in the `pay` method. Move the employee types to an `enum` and then per `enum` type has its own pay calculation. Like so:

```
package sandbox;

public enum Employee {
    SELLER() {
        @Override 
        int pay(int h) {
            int sum = (h > 20) ? 10 : 0;
            if (h > 8) { 
                sum = 20 * (h - 8);  
                sum += 80;
            } else {
                sum += 10 * h;
            }
            
            return sum;
        }
    },
    COOK() {
        @Override 
        int pay(int h) {
            int sum = (h > 20) ? 20 : 0;
            if (h > 8) { 
                sum = 30 * (h - 8);  
                sum += 15 * 8;
            } else {
                sum += 15 * h;
            }
            
            return sum;
        }
    },
    CHIEF() {
        @Override 
        int pay(int h) {
            int sum = (h > 20) ? 30 : 0;
            if (h > 8) { 
                sum = 66 * (h - 8);  
                sum += 22 * 8;
            } else {
                sum += 22 * h;
            }
            
            return sum;
        }       
    };
    
    abstract int pay(int h);
}
```

And the runner...

```
package sandbox;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Employee.SELLER.pay(5));
        System.out.println(Employee.COOK.pay(5));
        System.out.println(Employee.CHIEF.pay(5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With Java 8, the language acquired various functional bits which can be used for a functional kind of cleanup.

```
    import java.util.EnumMap;
    import java.util.function.IntFunction;

    public class Calc8 {

        public enum Employee {
            SELLER, COOK, CHIEF;
        }

        private final EnumMap<Employee, IntFunction<Integer>> map = new EnumMap<>(Employee.class);

        public Calc8() {
            map.put(Employee.SELLER, h -> {
                int sum = h > 8 ? 20 * (h - 8) + 80 : 10 * h;
                return h > 20 ? sum + 10 : sum;
            });
            map.put(Employee.COOK, h -> {
                int sum = h > 8 ? 30 * (h - 8) + (15 * 8) : 15 * h;
                return h > 20 ? sum + 20 : sum;

            });
            map.put(Employee.CHIEF, h -> {
                int sum = h > 8 ? 66 * (h - 8) + (22 * 8) : 22 * h;
                return h > 20 ? sum + 30 : sum;
            });
        }

        public int evaluate(Employee e, int value) {
            return map.get(e).apply(3);
        }

        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            Calc8 c = new Calc8();
            System.err.println(c.evaluate(Employee.CHIEF, 3) + " should be 66");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably should not build the Map for every `Calc8` instance. Also, it shouldnt even be a class in the first place.

Comment: Maybe, depends on the use case. The method `Calc8.evaluate()` may justify the existence of the class as it abstracts away the implementation.

Comment: Something like this was actually my first idea, why not build a Map for every Calc8 instance?

Comment: Because the values of the map have no state, a single instance is enough. This can be achieved by making it static or having Calc8 be a singleton.

Answer (score -1):

Write a switch block for the type inside pay function instead of using multiple if else statement.
Instead of giving type == SELLER , create a proper name and do the comparison.

Also an interface will be good for the Employees, with a factory pattern to get the object.

For code cleanup you can also add in plugins like:
https://www.sonarlint.org/